# IndexSet referring to index of the section instead of the row

Tags: swift, list, foreach, swiftui

I want to implement a swipe-to-delete functionality on a SwiftUI `Section` by using the `.onDelete` modifier. The problem is that it always deletes the first item in the list.

My view has a list with dynamic sections created with a `ForEach`.

```
struct SetListView : View {

    var setlist: Setlist
    var body : some View {

        List { 
            ForEach(setlist.sets) { 
                 SetSection(number: $0.id, songs: $0.songs) 
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
    }
}
```

In each section, there is another `ForEach` to create the dynamic rows:

```
private struct SetSection : View {

    var number: Int
    @State var songs: [Song]

    var body : some View {
        Section (header: Text("Set \(number)"), footer: Spacer()) {
            ForEach(songs) { song in
                SongRow(song: song)
            }
            .onDelete { index in
                self.songs.remove(at: index.first!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While debugging, I found out that the `IndexSet` is referring to the current section instead of the row. So when deleting items from the first section, always the first item gets deleted (as the index for the first section is 0).

Is this a bug in SwiftUI?

If not, then how could I get the index for the row?

Comment: This is definitely a problem with the structure of your data. Make sure that you update sets when you remove a specific song

Comment: I respectfully disagree. The problem is not happening after a song is removed, but before. I don’t think that my data structure has anything to do with the IndexSet passed to the closure.

Comment: I think it's a bug, or an unexpected behavior at least. If you have multiple ForEach () {}.onDelete () you get the position of the ForEach within all ForEach defined

Answer (score 12):

In simple terms, a solution to this problem is to pass the section to your deletion method by:

1. Adopting `RandomAccessCollection` on your source data.
2. Binding the section in your outer `ForEach` and then using it in your inner `ForEach`, passing it to your deletion method:

```
List {
  ForEach(someGroups.indices) { section in
    bind(self.someGroups[section]) { someGroup in
      Section(header: Text(someGroup.displayName)) {
        ForEach(someGroup.numbers) { number in
          Text("\(number)")
        }
        .onDelete { self.delete(at: $0, in: section) }
      }
    }
  }
}

func delete(at offsets: IndexSet, in section: Int) {
  print("\(section), \(offsets.first!)")
}
```

---

### A complete, contrived working example

([Also available in Gist form for convenience](https://gist.github.com/garrettmurray/4ec47079c97ff2fc64d63f735fa28c48)):

```
import SwiftUI

func bind<Value, Answer>(_ value: Value, to answer: (Value) -> Answer) -> Answer { answer(value) }

struct Example: View {

  struct SomeGroup: Identifiable, RandomAccessCollection {
    typealias Indices = CountableRange<Int>
    public typealias Index = Int;
    var id: Int
    var displayName: String
    var numbers: [Int]

    public var endIndex: Index {
      return numbers.count - 1
    }

    public var startIndex: Index {
      return 0
    }

    public subscript(position: Int) -> Int {
      get { return numbers[position] }
      set { numbers[position] = newValue }
    }

  }

  var someGroups: [SomeGroup] = {
    return [
      SomeGroup(id: 0, displayName: "First", numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4]),
      SomeGroup(id: 1, displayName: "Second", numbers: [1, 3, 5, 7])
    ]
  }()

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(someGroups.indices) { section in
        bind(self.someGroups[section]) { someGroup in
          Section(header: Text(someGroup.displayName)) {
            ForEach(someGroup.numbers) { number in
              Text("\(number)")
            }
            .onDelete { self.delete(at: $0, in: section) }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .listStyle(.grouped)
  }

  func delete(at offsets: IndexSet, in section: Int) {
    print("\(section), \(offsets.first!)")
  }

}
```

---

Many thanks to [@rob-mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff) who pointed me in the right direction for this solution via Twitter!

Comment: Thanks for the insight on how to pass the specific section to the delete method.  My sections are already an array of NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo's from a NSFetchedResultsController using a sectionNameKeyPath.  Very elegant.

Answer (score 10):

I had exactly the same problem. Turns out, SwiftUI's (current?) implementation does not recognize nested lists. This means that each `SetSection` in your `List` is interpreted as a single row even though you have a `ForEach` in it with the actual `SongRow`s. Hence, it the `IndexSet` (`index.first!`) always returns zero.

What I've also noticed is that even with a flat hierarchy such as..

```
List {
   Section {
       ForEach(...) {
          ...
       }
   }
   Section {
       ForEach(...) {
          ...
       }
   }
}
```

..individual rows cannot be moved between sections. This is also true when directly using two `ForEach`, i.e. without the `Section` wrappers.

We should probably file a report for each phenomenon.

Comment: Based on testing on my end, I would agree this is a bug. Sadly, it was not fixed in beta 3.

Comment: This wasn't fixed in beta 4 either, which makes me feel like I'm missing something. I saw some [references to `remove(atOffsets:)` being added in beta 4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/3349502-remove), but I don't see how that resolves the issue considering the IndexSet still has the wrong values.

Comment: Thankfully, I've found a working solution (posted as a new answer).

Comment: i have the same problem anyone find a solution?

Comment: @garrettmurray Your solution works well for deleting, but I also want to be able to move rows between the different sections. I'm curious if anyone has a solution for that, but I'm thinking it's a limitation of SwiftUI right now.

Comment: Sadly no, last I checked it was still a limitation.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to work fine on Xcode 12.5

I'm using it like this:

```
struct Sections: View {
    var items: [SomeData]
    private var sections: [Date: [SomeData]] {
        Dictionary(grouping: items, by: { $0.date })
    }
    private var headers: [Date] {
        sections.map({ $0.key }).sorted().reversed()
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(headers, id: \.self) { date in
                Section(header: Text(date.friendly) {
                    AList(items: sections[date]!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AList: View {
    var items: [SomeData]
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(items) { data in
            ...
        }
        .onDelete(perform: delete)
    }

    private func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        // You can use `items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)`
        for offset in offsets {
            let data = items[offset]
            print("\(data)") 
    // You can check here that this is the item that you want to remove and then you need to remove it from your data source. 
    // I'm using Realm and @Published vars that works fine, you should adapt to your logic.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra step in how to get into the item before deleting it.